# Is data validation incompatible between Excel 2007 and Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In machine A, I added data validation to some cells of a sheet using Excel 2010. The list of data validation values is in another tab in the same file. Then I moved the workbook to a shared folder. In machine B, I opened this in Excel 2007 and found the data validation had gone.

How can I debug/troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data validation (and conditional formatting) references can point to a different sheet in Excel 2010 and later. In versions earlier than 2010, though, this will not work.

You will need to create a **named range** for the cells that feed the data validation. So, in the sheet with the list of values, select the values and click the Formulas ribbon > Name Manager > New > enter a name for the range (or use your favourite technique to create a named range). Then set the data validation to the list option and let it refer to the range name, like

=MyRange

(where "MyRange" is the name of the range you just created) This will work in all current versions of Excel.

Comment: It works! Thanks you very much! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Data validation (and conditional formatting) references can point to a different sheet in Excel 2010 and later. In versions earlier than 2010, though, this will not work.

This is not true. In 2007 you can reference a range from another sheet by typing it in (it won't let you select the cells from the other sheet). e.g =Dropdowns!$D$3:$D$84

Not that this matters really for this problem which seems fairly bizarre!
Also thanks for the answer which did solve this issue which I was having.

Thanks

Comment: Actually neither of those statements are completely true nor are they completely false. You *can* type in a simple reference to a range in another sheet, like `=Dropdowns!$D$3:$D$84`, and it will work just fine. However, if you use that reference in a function, like `=INDEX(Dropdowns!$D$3:$D$84,1,1)`, it won't work.